# How to fix a leak in Hydration pack?

Tags: gear-care, hydration-bladders

Its somewhat wrong to say a leak, I should rather say a small hole. But how would you go about sealing/fixing it?

I know many of us would say, "Why so much trouble? trash it, and get a new one", but still I'd like to receive any ideas if you can think of.

[image]

Comment: Duct tape. Remember the saying: If you can Duck it, f*** it!

Comment: this ^ will work. But I never used it as a permanent fix. I threw it away afterwards and bought a new one.

Comment: You should be able to write a shell script for that.... :-)

Comment: @Brendan: LOL :D I'll give it a `try`!

Comment: Out of interest, do you know what caused the hole?

Comment: Hard to believe, it was tweezers from my swissknife. So I applied a bit of quick glue (Product: Fevi quick), that made it hard and it cracked open just like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Push the torn area up to the mouth and apply a bike tire patch to it from the inside (make sure it's dry). Then apply another patch from the outside. Where the two patches bond together will form a plug that should stand up better to water than a single patch.

Answer (score 7):

You could try something like [Shoe Goo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoe_Goo) or similar. Just dab on a small amount to seal the hole and ensure it doesn't stick to the opposite side of the hydration pack internally be keeping the sides separated until the Shoe Goo has dried.

I repaired a small hole in a waterproof Ortlieb bag quite a few years ago and it is still holding up as a repair.